# auto return type deduction with `std::move`

Tags: c++, c++14

The output from the below program will all be `1A` which is `A` when going through `c++filt -t`. I can see that the return type is deduced as value type rather than rvalue reference type when returning with `std::move`. It makes sense for most use cases of returning with `std::move`, but what is the reason for this? `std::move` returns an rvalue reference, but why is the return type automatically deduced as a value type?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <typeinfo>

struct A
: std::unique_ptr<int>
{
    auto f()
    {
        return A();
    }

    auto g()
    {
        return std::move(A());
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(A().f())).name() << ' ';
    std::cout << typeid(decltype(A().g())).name() << ' ';
    std::cout << typeid(A).name() << '\n';
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/20721887/576911 for `expression_name<T>()` and http://stackoverflow.com/a/20170989/576911 for `type_name<T>()`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two separate issues:

1. The tool you are using to check the return type is not fit for purpose.`typeid` strips referenceness then top-level cv-qualification; `typeid(int)`, `typeid(const int)` and `typeid(const int&&)` are the same thing. To test for actual type, use `std::is_same`; Boost.TypeIndex has `type_id_with_cvr`. There's also the trick where you do `template<class T> class TD;`, attempt to define a variable of type `TD</*type to be checked*/>`, and read out the type from  error message generated by the compiler.

but this is harmless here; both `f()` and `g()` indeed return `A` by value:

2. `auto f() { return /* stuff */; }` uses the `auto` rules, which never deduces a reference type. This is actually usually what you want - you don't really want to accidentally return references to things that have already died - which indeed is what your `g()` would do if it returned a reference!

To get "perfect returning", use `decltype(auto)`.

Answer (score 2):

See [typeid operator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/typeid) on cppreference:

> `typeid( type )` - Refers to a `std::type_info` object representing the type `type`. If `type` is a reference type, the result refers to the referenced type.

In other words, typeid() will discard/ignore any top-level reference qualifiers.

To avoid this, you can wrap your type in something, say a function signature like `void(your_type)`, which gives you the expected result of `A&&`

Example:
http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d6af3eff8216246f

Answer (score 1):

> I can see that the return type is deduced as value type rather than rvalue reference type when returning with std::move. It makes sense for most use cases of returning with std::move, but what is the reason for this? std::move returns an rvalue reference, but why is the return type automatically deduced as a value type?

Plain `auto` type deduction is the same as plain template argument deduction (except `std::initializer_list` case). In other words, `auto` never deduces a reference, unless universal reference `&&` is used.

`decltype(auto)` on the other hand, performs similar type deduction to `auto` but also adds extra `decltype` deduction rules, that allow for deducing of l-value and r-value references. This is what you may like to use for your return type if you would like it to be deduced as reference.

Answer (score 0):

`typeid(expression)` queries information about the *static* type of `expression`.   For any references, including rvalue references which is what  `std::move()` returns, that means querying the type of the object that the reference refers to, not the type of the reference itself.