# Get type of expression at compile time

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

While programming with the `auto` keyword it would sometimes be convenient to know the type that is used by the compiler at compile time. It does not matter if the compilation aborts where I need to know the type. Simple example:

```
std::vector< int > s{1, 2, 3}; 

for (auto elem : s) {
    elem = 5;
}   

for (auto elem : s) {
    std::cout << elem << std::endl;
}
```

will print

```
1
2
3
```

because elem is of type `int`, not `int&`. It would be nice to try compile the code and get the type of `elem` to catch such mistakes early.

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. Any code that you would write to ensure that `elem` is a reference seems quite a bit longer than having written `auto&& elem` to begin with.

Comment: You could use [`std::is_reference`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_reference) together with [`static_assert`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert). But it adding that to every loop is more work than just making sure that you use the correct type to begin with. And no, there's no way of making the compiler do the check for you, as the assignment is not invalid in any way.

Comment: Your example looks like a good reason for a compiler warning. For example, my compiler says `warning: variable ‘elem’ set but not used`.

Comment: It would be nice to have a generic method to show the type, this is just a very simple example where it could be helpful.

Comment: IIRC, `auto` is never a reference type. Are you expecting the compiler to deduce that you intended to use a reference from the existence of the assignment and warn you?

Comment: `expression_name`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20721887/576911

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Classical way is to declare template structure without definition:

```
template <typename> struct Debug;
```

and then use it:

```
template struct Debug<std::string>;
```

or

```
for (auto elem : s) {
    Debug<decltype(elem)>{};

    elem = 5;
}
```

Message error looks like

```
error: explicit instantiation of 'struct Debug<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >' before definition of template
 template struct Debug<std::string>;
                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

error: invalid use of incomplete type 'struct Debug<int>'
         Debug<decltype(e)>{};
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1c75195bad3ce458)

BTW, now some IDEs show the type when mouse is over `auto` or the variable.

Comment: Great! I like this even better -- unfortunately I could not find this type of solution with my Google-foo :(

Answer (score 2):

Actually I just found an answer to my own question:

```
template<typename T>
void show_type_abort_helper()
{
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
}

#define show_type_abort(x) show_type_abort_helper< decltype(x) >()
```

Usage:

```
std::vector< int > s{1, 2, 3};

for (auto elem : s) {
    show_type_abort(elem);
    elem = 5;
}
```

Produces the following error message with `g++` (version 6.1.1):

```
$ g++ test.cpp
test.cpp: In instantiation of ‘void show_type_abort_helper() [with T = int]’:
                                                                       ^^^
test.cpp:17:9:   required from here
test.cpp:7:12: error: return-statement with a value, in function returning 'void' [-fpermissive]
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
```

Check the output at `T = int` to see the compiler uses `int` as type. This seems to work with clang as well:

```
$ clang++-3.8 -std=c++11 test.cpp
test.cpp:7:5: error: void function 'show_type_abort_helper' should not return a value [-Wreturn-type]
    return __PRETTY_FUNCTION__;
    ^      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
test.cpp:17:9: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'show_type_abort_helper<int>' requested here
                                                                                                  ^^^
        show_type_abort(elem);
```

Changing to `for (const auto& elem : s)` gives

```
with T = const int&
         ^^^^^^^^^^
```

or

```
show_type_abort_helper<const int &>
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

So it seems I can find out the type at compile time and abort. This just came in handy for a very complex type that consisted of several typedefs and template parameters where I just could not see what was going on.