# How to distiguish between an rvalue and rvalue reference in a function parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

When passed a parameter, I would like to distinguish between these two cases in a function parameter, like this:

```
int rvalue();
int&& rvalue_ref();

f(rvalue());
f(rvalue_ref());
```

However, when I try with forwarding references like this:

```
int rvalue()
{
    return 1;
}

int&& rvalue_ref(int i)
{
    return std::move(i);
}

template<class T>
void f(T&& x)
{
    if (std::is_rvalue_reference<T>())
    {
        std::cout << "Rvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    else if (std::is_lvalue_reference<T>())
    {
        std::cout << "Lvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not a reference" << std::endl;
    }
}

int main() 
{
    f(rvalue()); // Should print "Not a reference"
    f(rvalue_ref(1)); // Should print "Rvalue reference"
}
```

It prints out "Not a reference" for both cases. Is there a way to distinguish both cases in C++?

Comment: Why do you want to distinguish between those two cases in the first place?

Comment: You seem to actually be asking how to behave differently for xvalue argument than prvalue argument

Comment: Haha, I caused an internal compiler error in g++ 5.2 while trying something

Comment: Isn't `rvalue_ref` [undefined behavior](https://goo.gl/s4WHg2)?

Comment: @user657267 sure is!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see how to do this solely using function parameter. The distinction between xvalue and prvalue may be lost in the function call.

But you can do it with a macro that calls `decltype` on the argument, before calling the function. Here is an example that calls your function with the relevant information as a second parameter.  I borrowed code from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16637945/1505939).

```
#include <iostream>

int rvalue()
{
    return 1;
}

int&& rvalue_ref(int &&i)   // Modified signature to avoid return reference to local variable (ty. user657267)
{
    return std::move(i);
}

template<typename T>
struct value_category {
    // Or can be an integral or enum value
    static constexpr auto value = "prvalue";
};

template<typename T>
struct value_category<T&> {
    static constexpr auto value = "lvalue";
};

template<typename T>
struct value_category<T&&> {
    static constexpr auto value = "xvalue";
};

// Double parens for ensuring we inspect an expression,
// not an entity
#define VALUE_CATEGORY(expr) value_category<decltype((expr))>::value

#define f(X) f_(X, VALUE_CATEGORY(X)) 

template<class T>
void f_(T&& x, char const *s)
{
    std::cout << s << '\n';
}

int main() 
{
    f(rvalue()); // Should print "Not a reference"
    f(rvalue_ref(1)); // Should print "Rvalue reference"
    int j; f(j);
}
```

Output:

```
prvalue
xvalue
lvalue
```

Of course you can trivially modify the strings to suit, or replace them with enums etc.

Comment: Does it distinguish lvalue and prvalue?

Comment: @NickyC added example

Answer (score 0):

The reason why your code said 'Not a reference' is that you passed `T` to `std::std::is_lvalue_reference<>` and `std::std::is_rvalue_reference<>`.
You should use decltype() to get its original type.

```
template<class T>
void f( T&& x )
{
    if ( std::is_lvalue_reference< decltype( x ) >() )
    {
        std::cout << "Lvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    else if ( std::is_rvalue_reference < decltype( x ) >() )
    {
         std::cout << "Rvalue reference" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Not a reference" << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: This outputs `Rvalue reference` twice for me . Did you try it ? (If you get different results please post a MCVE, as it would mean one of us has a bugged compiler)

Comment: Maybe if you try `decltype(std::forward<T>(x))`?

Comment: because everything is ravlue in test case above ;)

Comment: well you didn't comply with OP's requirements which were that `f(rvalue()` and `f(rvalue_ref(1))` produce different output

Comment: as template funcation takes reference(&&), I think we can only distringush `lvalure reference` or 'rvalue refence`