# Is the reference returned from the function rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11, reference, rvalue

```
int a = 20;
int& fun(){
     return a;
}
int main(){
     fun();
     return 0;
}
```

Is the reference returned by func rvalue by itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. If a function returns an lvalue reference, then calling it gives you an lvalue.

If it returns an rvalue reference, you get an xvalue, and if it returns by value, you get a prvalue.

Also, strictly saying the result of calling the function is not a reference. It's an lvalue expression of type `int`.

---

In general, you can determine value category of any expression by applying `decltype` to it. It will add reference-ness to the type of the expression, indicating its category: `&` for lvalues, `&&` for xvalues, and nothing for prvalues.

Expressions themselves can't have reference types, so this added reference-ness will not conflict with their type.

For example, `decltype(fun())` is `int &`, proving that it's an lvalue.

Even though doesn't apply in this case, note that `decltype` handles variable names differently from any other expressions (giving you the type of the variable, rather than expression type + value category). The workaround is to add a second set of `(...)` around the variable name, which makes `decltype` treat it as any other expression.

Comment: So references can not be rvalues? Only lvalues?

Comment: @RostyslavBuryak Hmm. When you say "a reference", you normally mean a reference type (e.g. `int &`), or a variable that has a reference type (e.g. `int &x`). Value category (lvalues, rvalues, and other -values), on the other hand, is a property of an expression, an neither types nor variables are expressions. Yes, a variable name can be used as an expression (e.g. the second occurence of `b` in `int a=42; int &b = a; cout << b;` is an expression) - in that case the resulting expression is always an lvalue, regardless of whether the variable is reference or not, and if it's an rvalue reference.

Comment: But you don't have reference variables in your question, so this doesn't help in this case.

Comment: > *In general, you can determine value category of any expression by applying decltype to it.* If anyone's curious look at [this SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637945/empirically-determine-value-category-of-c11-expression)

Comment: @RostyslavBuryak I suggest figuring out the [terminology](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/basic_concepts) first: what are "variables", "objects", "expressions", etc.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat actually understanding that value category is a property of an expression really helps in understanding of value categories at all