# How to distinguish between pr-values and x-values

Tags: c++, parameter-passing, xvalue, value-categories, prvalue

In the following code,

```
#include <utility>

struct literal_type
{
    // ...
};

class my_type
{
public:
    my_type(literal_type const& literal);    // (1)
    my_type(literal_type     && literal);    // (2)

    // ...
};

void foo()
{
    literal_type literal_var { /* ... */ };

    my_type var1 (literal_var);       // Calls (1)
    my_type var2 (std::move(var));    // Calls (2)
    my_type var3 (literal_type{});    // Calls (2)
}
```

I understand that the value category of the argument passed in the constructor of `var1` is an l-value, `var2` is an x-value and `var3` is a pr-value.

I would like that the constructor of `my_type` accepts `var3`, while `var1` and `var2` should emit a compiler error. `var1` is easily solved by removing constructor (1), but I cannot find the way to distinguish between `var2` and `var3`.

Is there any way to distinguish between x-value references and pr-value references?

Comment: Refer to [Empirically determine value category of C++11 expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16637945/empirically-determine-value-category-of-c11-expression)

Comment: It would help to create a minimal reproducible example https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Make the parameter type non-copyable and non-movable, and pass by value. I don't think there's an other way. But why do you need this?

Comment: **An expression in C++ never have a reference type**. Moreover, I don't think the standard uses the term "pr-value references".

Comment: The question and answer are being [discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/420670).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't. You can distinguish xvalue and prvalues at the call site, but once you've passed them to a function that accepts them, you've lost the information of which of the two it was.

The reason is that the [value category](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category) is a property of an expression, and inside of the constructors `literal` has always the lvalue value category, because it's the name of a parameter. The value category of the corresponding argument, instead, can be encoded in the type of the parameter if you declare it as forwarding reference, but that will carry you as far to distinguish lvalue vs rvalue, not giving you the lvalue vs xvalue vs prvalue granularity.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <utility>

struct literal_type
{
};

class my_type
{
public:
    my_type(literal_type const&) {}
    template<typename T>
    my_type(T&&) {
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<T, literal_type>);     // passes
        static_assert(std::is_same_v<T&&, literal_type&&>); // passes
    }

};

void foo()
{
    literal_type literal_var { };

    my_type var2 (std::move(literal_var));    // Calls (2)
    my_type var3 (literal_type{});    // Calls (2)
}
```

And if the original value category of the argument is not encoded in the type of the parameter, where would you ever get it from?

After all, the purpose of `std::move` is exactly to dress up a value like a temporary (whether it was already or not).

In other words, if you use `f(std::move(nonTemporary))` and `f(temporary)` at the call site, why would you ever want `nonTemporary` to be treated differently from `temporary`? If you really want, then you're misusing `std::move` in the first place.

---

I saw the suggestion of *Make the parameter type non-copyable and non-movable, and pass by value*, but I would never take such a route before [clarifying first what you actually want to do](https://xyproblem.info/).