tool do determine the value category an expression: understanding the result when using references
Looking into definition of value-categories, I tried a snippet proposed here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16638081/21691539
template <typename T>
struct value_category {
    // Or can be an integral or enum value
    static constexpr auto value = "prvalue";
};

template <typename T>
struct value_category<T&> {
    static constexpr auto value = "lvalue";
};

template <typename T>
struct value_category<T&&> {
    static constexpr auto value = "xvalue";
};

// Double parens for ensuring we inspect an expression,
// not an entity
#define VALUE_CATEGORY(expr) value_category<decltype((expr))>::value

But testing it I don't understand its output in a situation implying references. Here is my "testbench":
#include <iostream>

struct S {
    int val;
    int& rval = val;
};

int f();
int& rf();

// VALUE_CATEGORY as in previous snippet

#define SHOW_CATEGORY(expr) std::cout << #expr << "\t" << VALUE_CATEGORY(expr) << '\n';

int main() {
    SHOW_CATEGORY(f());
    SHOW_CATEGORY(rf());    // expecting prvalue, got lvalue
    SHOW_CATEGORY(S{}.val);
    SHOW_CATEGORY(S{}.rval);    // expecting xvalue, got lvalue
}

LIVE
and the output
f()      prvalue
rf()     lvalue
S{}.val  xvalue
S{}.rval lvalue

In both cases where the expression is related to a reference, I'm getting an unexpected lvalue.
Is the snippet right and, in this case why? Is it wrong, then what would be the correct value category (and also why)?

NB from https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/basic.lval#4.4 I've got that S{}.rval is not an xvalue though I'd like to know the rationale.

rf() is lvalue expression. See this answer in the dupe that says: "A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type"

Suppose S were defined as struct S { std::string& rval; }; and you had a function S g(). When you write std::string s = g().rval; do you want s to use the move constructor from g().rval? That rval might be a reference to a std::string that is not temporary.

@user12002570 with the help of your quote I found the ref in the standard, thanks. I suppose that the rational is that the ref might "point" to a static variable that could be modified?

@Oersted Also note that the reference you quoted [basic.lval#4.4] doesn't apply for S{}.rval because rval has a reference-type.

@user12002570 I don't get it. [basic.lval#4.4] explicitly says that S{}.val is an xvalue but  that S{}.rval may not be? Am I not right. Anyway, it does not tell me what it is...

@RaymondChen sorry, I don't get your line of reasoning... Perhaps am I missing a link between move semantic and value category?

@Oersted What you're looking for is basicref. It explains the observed behavior as explained in my answer below.


Is the snippet right and, in this case why?

Yes as explained below.
First S{}.rval is an lvalue expression as per basic.ref that states:

If E2 is declared to have type “reference to T”, then E1.E2 is an lvalue of type T.

In your example, rval has int& which means S{}.rval is an lvalue expression.

Next the call rf() is also an lvalue expression. From expr.call:

A function call is an lvalue if the result type is an lvalue reference type or an rvalue reference to function type, an xvalue if the result type is an rvalue reference to object type, and a prvalue otherwise.


Clear! I'm just missing the rational, especially for S{}.rval.

@Oersted I would recommend asking a new question specifically for the rationale. In particular, in your question you can ask directly: "What is the rational for S{}.rval being an lvalue expression". Currently there seems to be two questions in your current post. One about what the standard says and second about the rationale. I am sure about the first question about the standard but not about the rationale. So it is usually recommended to ask one question per post because people might know answer to one part but not other. You can link this question in your new question.

S{} is expiring, so S{}.rval is expiring, but the thing that S{}.rval references is not expiring. By analogy, consider struct S2 { int* p; }; Then S2{}.p is an expiring int*, but *S2{}.p is a non-expiring int.
